# git-tf : git-tf: Unknown host "server"

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc, git-tf

I have TFS (on-premesies ) having my server `name:8080` and I am able to clone repo to my system but I am trying to clone tfs repo to another system. Below is my code :-

```
git tfs clone lp-r90c2gwk:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/SampleProject D:\GitTemp
```

but getting error **"git-tf : git-tf: Unknown host server"**. Can you give me idea how can I clone tfs(on-premises) repo to another system?

Comment: NO I can not push using git-tf

Comment: Is there any way to import tfs repo to git in local machine???

Comment: Use Git-tfs instead. Git-tf is deprecated. While it's supposed to still work, git-tfs is supported to work: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

Comment: No, still Not able to import tfs repo to another system.

Comment: Did you switch to git-tfs? If so, can you update your post with the new steps you took? What TFS version are you working with? can you ping the server by its name? Does the server name resolve over DNS, or are you targetting the Windows Netwoking name?

Comment: git tfs clone http://lp-r90c2gwk:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/SampleProject D:\GitTemp .  TFS Administration 2017 . I ping in my system It is pinging .

Comment: `git tfs` requires the full project url incl protocol (e.g. `http://lp-r279793847:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`). You can't set the output path as far as I remember and must execute from the directory you want to clone to? Can you test whether your command works against VSTS. Try specifying the `--debug` flag for more details?

Comment: I used  git tfs clone http://lp-r90c2gwk:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/SampleProject  . I jave mentioned url https://lp-r90c2gwk, but getting below error                                                                    
 TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server https://lp-r90c2gwk:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection.
Technical information (for administrator):
  The remote name could not be resolved: 'lp-r90c2gwk'
The remote name could not be resolved: 'lp-r90c2gwk'

Comment: Actually in my system it worked.I can able to access url , but in different system It is not accessible.

Comment: @PriyaRani Please check if you have installed the `git tf` or `Git-tfs` on the "different" system which not worked. Also make sure you have set the correct credential to access to the TFS on that machine.

Comment: If it can't connect or resolve the hostname, it can't. There may be a network issue that prevents the access.

Comment: @Andy- Git tf or Git-tfs installed on different system  and I m not able to access TFS  url itself on different machine, not able to ping even ip adress. Even I opened port itslef .

Comment: @Jessehouwing -  Yes there is network issue bit different which I m not getting .How yo resolve that

Comment: @PriyaRani There are many situations to cause the network issue, you need to ask your IT administrator to troubleshoot that. This article for your reference [How to troubleshoot network connectivity problems in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/936211/how-to-troubleshoot-network-connectivity-problems-in-internet-explorer)